# Unable to add shape to geom_points

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(Errors) +
  geom_point(aes(MAE,MSE), shape=names )+
  xlim(0.6,0.8)+
  ylim(1.75,2.5)
```

I am trying to plot my MSE's against the MAE's for my different models.
But I can not visualize which data point belongs to which model.

Comment: `shape` is outside `aes`

Comment: looks like you have been just faster. But why not providing it rather as an answer than a comment?

Comment: @mnist IMO there's no question, just a typo (parenthesis at the wrong position)

Comment: In my experience, this is a common mistake with ggplot and a lack of understanding how `aes()`works rather than just a typo. And why not provide an answer to all questions? So the community knows that a problem is solved?

Comment: @mnist simply answering all questions doesn't help curate useful content. If questions are off-topic, as typos/non-reproducible minor issues are, answers just add clutter. SO isn't just intended to get quick answers to specific questions, but to create community resources that are useful in the future. An answer to this question would mostly just be a copy of the documentation

Comment: Okay, when a question itself is off-topic then it should be closed and no answers are needed. Agreed. However, as long as a question is not closed then I do not see the advantage of a comment, that is actually an answer, over an answer. In my opinion: either close a question that is not worth to be on SO or, if the question itself is worth to be on SO, then it should also be worth to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map shapes to information in your data, you have to specify the variable within `aes()`

```
ggplot(Errors) +
  geom_point(aes(MAE, MSE, shape = names)) +
  xlim(0.6, 0.8) +
  ylim(1.75, 2.5)
```

Comment: you could accept it as an answer so the community knows the problem is solved ;)